# Is it possible to remove activation lock on a 2022 Mac Studio?

Tags: macos, security, activation-lock, find-my-mac, mac-studio

I bough a 2022 Mac Studio on eBay that has activation lock (Find My must still be enabled). I thought it could be reset like you can on the 2020 MacBook Air that has the T2 security chip, but I don't think this one has that and am not able to fix the activation lock.

**The computer stats...**

- Apple M1 Max with 10-core CPU and 24-core GP
- 64GB RAM
- 1TB Storage

[image: Service and Support Coverage]

Are there any technical or process methods to use this device?

Comment: You should contact the seller to find out why. It also might have [been stolen](https://notebooks.com/2011/05/10/how-to-avoid-buying-a-stolen-mac-apple-store-robbed-of-24-macbooks-in-30-seconds-video/). Here's the link to check if it is [still under warranty](https://checkcoverage.apple.com).

Comment: @IconDaemon, the seller stated that they had won the computer at a local auction. I also attached the Service and Support Coverage from Apple as of today. Do you have any ideas about unlocking it?

Comment: @IconDaemon, also is there any way to know if it is reported as stolen, like if someone stole it and it ended up on eBay?

Comment: Return this stolen merchandise to the seller and get your money back through eBay.

Comment: @MarcWilson I ended up returning it to the eBay seller. BUT just because it's locked doesn't mean it's stolen. If someone dies and didn't share password with friends/family, their computer is rendered useless and can't even be wiped and used again.

Comment: So, no one has attempted to answer my question yet! Is it possible in any way shape or form to wipe a Mac Studio 2022 or is it bricked if it's activation locked?

Comment: Sure it is.  You contact Apple, provide proof of ownership (an eBay transaction is NOT proof), and Apple removes the Activation Lock.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201441

Comment: At stated earlier... what if a parent dies and you have no way to prove ownership or know their password since it was their computer. Apple doesn't own the computer the kids would at that point. I'm just wanting to know now even though I don't have a computer with this issue. For over 30 years I've been able to format a hard drive on a Windows computer and now these Macs be bricks if you don't have a password or approval from Apple. Still waiting for an answer if there's a way to format things. Could someone even entertain the thought please????

Comment: Late comment, but if you put a security feature on, you need to be prepared to deal with the consequences.  Apple has a defined process to override/remove the lockout.

Comment: Thank you @MarcWilson I'm still looking for answers for curiosity's sake at this point since I'm do computer admin work for people. I still want to know if the ONE AND ONLY humanly possible sub-twenty-thousand-dollar solution to fix a non T1 or T2 chip MacBook is to have Apple unlock it by answering security questions or knowing the iCloud password. I don't like owning a potential brick if passwords are lost ha ha.

Comment: So now it's devolved to a device that doesn't support Activation Lock in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I really do want to know. Anyone? Somebody? There’s data locking and then there’s hardware locking. Can someone else address if there’s any possibility to ever use the hardware ever again in an iCloud activation lock situation. For thirty years computer passwords vastly only protected data so this is new behavior to me. The data is the sensitive info, not the hardware. iPhones to date are not hardware locked when you forget a password https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306. This is a legit question.

Comment: Except iPhones are.  iPhones support Activation Lock.

Comment: Did you ever find this out? I’m in the exact scenario you posed with my family. I provided Apple a death cert and now I’m being told I also need a court order. If you find a bypass I’d love to know! TIA.

Comment: There not a way to get around it that I know of. It's Apple's choice to do this, but to me it seems that if data security is the goal, encryption of the drive is adequate. Privacy is only for data, not hardware since hardware is identical to thousands of other computers out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple can remove activation lock as part of their support process.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201441

> If you need help removing Activation Lock and have proof of purchase documentation, you can start an [Activation Lock support request](https://al-support.apple.com/).

Comment: This is the only method I'm aware of that works. I don't agree that hardware should be bricked though. Only data has privacy concerns. Nevertheless, this is what Apple is doing.